# Which is the best method to parse json data at client side?

Tags: json, gwt, jackson, jsni

I am using Jackson to write the data and using gwt-json at client side to parse the data. I am 
rendering the data through Dictionary at client side which is slow, so i want to make it speed in parsing.
I tried with JSNI with eval() instead of Dictionary and it is doing good job compare to dictionary in terms of speed and but it is having security problems.

```
 private List<Party> getPartyListFormJackson() {    

    String name = "partyListInfo"; // jsp variable     
    String partyListStr = getString(name);     
    JSONArray partyJSONArray = JSONParser.parse(partyListStr).isArray();    
    for(int i=0; i < partyJSONArray.size(); i++) {    
      JSONObject partyJSONObject = (JSONObject) partyJSONArray.get(i);   
      Party party = VsJacksonFactory.getParty(partyJSONObject);    
      partyList.add(party);     
    }    
    return partyList;    
  }    

  public static native String getString(String name) /*-{     
  return eval('$wnd.'+ name);     
}-*/;
```

in above which method can i use instead of eval()?

Can any body have any idea about this, to make it better.

Thanks
MSNaidu

Answer (score 1):

GWT has basically 3 ways to parse JSON (this is without third-party libs):

- `JSONParser` is the legacy API. It's cumbersome to work with but is most flexible, particularly when you work with *dynamic* JSON (where the structure is not fixed in advance)
- `JsonUtils.safeEval()` with `JavaScriptObject`s (aka *overlay types*) is the most lightweight; it'll use native `JSON.parse()` where supported, and will validate the JSON with a regexp before handing it to `eval()` otherwise
- `AutoBeans` is the latest addition. It works in GWT and in the JVM (server-side, Android clients, etc.)

All approaches can also work when you have a `JavaScriptObject` instance rather than a JSON string (you mention `Dictionary`, which is not about JSON; this is why I add this precision).

Comment: I am using the dictionary instead of Jsni, the dictionary is taking time to get the data from my jsp.

Comment: There's hardly anything lighter-weight than `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Dictionary` besides plain JSNI. Are your perf issues in devmode or prod mode?

Comment: i want to replace eval()..method in jsni

Comment: So you're `eval()`'ing some JSON, _injecting_ the object into a global variable and using `Dictionary` to read back from it? Anyway, the safer equivalent of `eval()` is `JsonUtils`; both `JSONParser` and `AutoBeans` delegate to it for parsing, the rest is about higher-level APIs. Choose your poison.

Comment: Why do you use `eval()` !? `return $wnd[name]`. The question is rather: why are you using JSON rather than a JS object (using the JS object literal notation, which is very similar to JSON)

Comment: I am writing the data into object mapper, and i get it through jsp, and jsp will return string.                                                                                                                                       my code is at server side.. req.setAttribute("partyList", partyListJacksonStr); partyListJacksonStr is a string returned by object mapper.

Comment: Maybe it's JS-safe and you can write it as `var foo = {the json}` rather than `var foo = "{the json}"`, that way you don't have to parse JSON on the client side; `$wnd.foo` is a `JavaScriptObject` that you can cast to an overlay type or pass to `JSONObject` constructor.

Comment: Thank you thomas..., and i want to one more thing where the deserialization have done this process?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I did what you have suggested, but for heavy data it is not able to carry to the gwt side.